# How to programmatically remove "values" from Google Sheets pivot tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the Spreadsheet App [Pivot Table class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-table) to programmatically create and update pivot tables in google sheets. The [Pivot Group class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-group) used to display breakout groups has ways to remove the groups just like you can in the UI. The [Pivot Value class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-value) appears however has no way to remove a Pivot Value from the table if I don't want to use it. Is there any workaround other than recreating the entire pivot table?

Comment: You can try the sheets API via advanced Google services in apps script and see if the API offers the features you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Sheets API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/pivot-tables#modifying_and_deleting_pivot_tables):

> There are no explicit requests to modify or delete a pivot table; **instead, you just use the updateCells request with different cell contents**
>
> - To modify a pivot table, **create a modified PivotTable definition and update the cell using that**, exactly as if you were adding a new pivot table.
> - To delete a pivot table, update the cell to have empty contents (for an example of this, see the Delete a pivot table sample).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. While I understand that this is true for the Google Sheets API, I am using the Spreadsheet App which appears to function differently as you can update the pivot table at least for a Pivot Group.